# Different Intents passing through multiple activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-button

I have five activities say **A**,**B**,**C**,**D** and **E**. Each activity has two buttons **Yes** & **No**, contains **1** & **0** value respectively.

**I need to do the following thing.**

---

If user press yes button of activity A, **user + (only) yes button's** value **(int 1)** passes to activity B and if user presses no button then **user + (only) no button's** value **(int 0)** will move to activity B. how can I do this to send only the specific value whose button was pressed at activity A. how can I determine which button was pressed by the user and then passed the already save values **1/0** to next activity.

**Now Here comes the tricky part.**

---

At **activity B** if user presses yes/no button then, the **received int value of activity's A**   **+**    **int value of activity's B** move to activity C. Similarly At activity C if user presses yes, then along this yes int value i.e **1 of activity C + values of activity A & activity B** also passes to activity D. ***The very same process goes on until user came to last one i.e activity E.***

> How can I achieve this behaviour via intent or sharedpreferrence or any other way?

Please share some sample code as I am new to android. As I am failed to get through this and I found no example from internet which can lead me to solve this issue, after doing lot of searching.

Answer (score 1):

Here is logic,
Implement view onclicklistener and set listener to buttons.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(A.this, B.class);
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.Yes:
                    intent.putExtra("value",1);
                break;
                case R.id.NO:
                    intent.putExtra("value",0);
                    break;
           }
            startActivity(intent);
```

create intent object show in about code.

Comment: You can save the value of previous activity to pass it to forward activity.

Comment: thanks to share the logic of 1st half. I have tried myself, on activity B I can receive intent from A. But the second half remains unsolved the int values which I want to pass from activity B to activity C is not achieving, remember at activity B we have two int values 1st is value from activity A and second is of activity B. Similarly as the user moves to next activity the number of int values will increases as each activity will send tts value +values from previous ones.

Comment: How can I save the value of previous activity to pass it to next activity ?

Comment: Okay for 2nd half, let say you received integer value of 1 from activity .
create int(sum- is variable name) in activity B and assign value to ti got from activity, now when you click on button  pass the sum of value of activity A + value of current activity B
                    intent.putExtra("value", sum + 1 ); where 1 is value of current activity.

Comment: @Keyar Thumar thanks bro. It is working perfectly. The logic you have shared to me has assisted me to complete my second app. Really appreciate your logic. :)

Comment: @AliShah Do contact me @kjthumbar@gmail.com if you have any work.